# CentOS 5 kickstart requesting .discinfo in incrementing disc# folders

Tags: centos, centos5, pxe-boot, razor

I am attempting to PXE boot a CentOS 5 installation and it is hanging at anaconda start without errors. I can see on the web server side that it is requesting the same .discinfo file over and over again incrementing the disc subfolder number each time until I eventually power off the machine:

```
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc1/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc1/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc2/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc2/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc3/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc3/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc4/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc4/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc5/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc5/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc6/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc6/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc7/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc7/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc8/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc8/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc9/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc9/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc10/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc10/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc11/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc11/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc12/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc12/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc13/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc13/.discinfo'
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc14/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc14/.discinfo'
...
/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc1765/.discinfo
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2//disc1765/.discinfo'
```

I have trimmed down my kickstart file to be fairly minimal:

```
install
url --url=http://10.10.30.9:8027/razor/image/os/zCVSoQsb9BFCSIecae3f2
text
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
rootpw <removed>
network --hostname api3.mydomain.com
firewall --disabled
authconfig --enableshadow
selinux --disabled
timezone --utc America/Los_Angeles
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart
reboot
%packages --nobase
@core
```

I am using dnsmasq to hand out DHCP and TFTP and iPXE to handle the booting of the install. This part seems to happen fine. It hangs up when it passes loading the disk controller drivers and starts anaconda.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Is there SAN storage attached to the server?

Comment: No, only 2 local logical drives exported from RAID

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the installation tree is setup correctly.  `.discinfo` describes the contents of a CentOS ISO.  Here's the RHEL5 equivalent:

```
# cat .discinfo
1328205744.315196
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.8
x86_64
1
Server/base
Server/RPMS
Server/pixmaps
```

Can you find a file named `.discinfo` anywhere on your system?